# How to reset sj:autocompleter input text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, struts2

I am using struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.1.jar plugin, In my form I am using the sj:autocompleter element

```
<sj:autocompleter id="paymentTypeCode" name="paymentTypeCode" list="paymentTypeDropdownMap" selectBox="true" selectBoxIcon="true"/>
```

The firebug shows the generated html as below -

```
<input id="paymentTypeCode" value="" name="paymentTypeCode" type="hidden">
<select style="display: none;" name="paymentTypeCode_widget" id="paymentTypeCode_widget">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Cash</option>
    <option value="2">Cheque</option>
    <option value="3">DD</option>


</select><span class="s2j-combobox"><span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" aria-live="polite" role="status">3 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span><input autocomplete="off" class="s2j-combobox-input ui-autocomplete-input" title=""><a title="" aria-disabled="false" role="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only s2j-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text"></span></a></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var options_paymentTypeCode_widget = {};
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.hiddenid = "paymentTypeCode";
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.selectBox = true;
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.selectBoxIcon = true;
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.forceValidOption = true;

    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.jqueryaction = "autocompleter";
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.id = "paymentTypeCode_widget";
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.name = "paymentTypeCode_widget";
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.href = "#";
    options_paymentTypeCode_widget.formids = "sysForm";


jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(jQuery('#paymentTypeCode_widget'),options_paymentTypeCode_widget);

 });
</script>
```

I want to reset the autocompleter selections using javascript with the button element as below -

```
<input type="button" value=" Reset " onclick="resetSelection();">
```

The javascript is as below -

```
<script>
function resetSelection(){
document.getElementById("paymentTypeCode").value="";//Resets the selected value

//To reset the input text displayed
$("#paymentTypeCode input").resetCSS();//Not working

$("#paymentTypeCode").val("");//Not working

$("#paymentTypeCode_widget").val("");//Not working
}
</script>
```

I am able to reset the selected values in the hidden field, but I am struggling with the displayed input text, I tried many options suggested but nothing seems to work & the input text does not seem to have any effect.

In some of my forms I have multiple autocompleter elements & need the reset thing to work based on few validations. I am aware the input text generated needs to be targeted but it does not have any ID.

Comment: `val` isn't working because `#paymentTypeCode_widget` is `select` element not a text field.

Comment: @Aleksandr I am not sure how to get this working as the input type element does not have any ID as displayed by firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply I wanted to close this pending question with the solution I had used then. Here it is -

```
function resetSelection(){
    $('.s2j-combobox').find('input').val('');
}
```

Note - If you have multiple `sj:autocompleter` widgets on the form make sure you use the closest unique parent element id or class to find `.s2j-combobox`.

Hope this helps someone stuck with the same issue.